# Are there any fan-made Adventure Time RPGs?

Tags: game-recommendation

I know that there are no official Adventure Time RPGs. Are there any fan-made ones out there? I'd be willing to accept adaptations of the characters/setting to other systems, as well as standalone games.

Comment: As this is a [tag:system-recommendation] question, please adhere to both the [FAQ] and the rules for subjective questions as outlined in [Good Subjective, Bad Subjective](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/) and on [our Meta](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/a/1071/760).  In particular, all responses should be based on actual experience and contain references and examples whenever possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Second search hit: [Unofficial Adventure Time RPG](http://bloodghost.tumblr.com/post/28417331911/its-here-after-many-months-the-utterly-complete), a hack of D&D 4e.

Comment: Looks pretty nice, even if I'm not a fan of D&D 4e. Thanks!

Comment: Come on SSD, you know the system-rec rules...

Answer (score -1):

This has already been answered, but I'll contribute anyways with the little knowledge I have.

Savage Worlds is the system I use. It's easier to learn and run than 4e and ironically has more options. You only need the Core Book (Deluxe Edition recommended), a little imagination, and understanding of the rules. Finn the Human is a pretty straightforward character, just grab the Warrior Template and make him a child. Jake the Dog? There are stats for dogs on the Bestiary, just create a power to make him stretch and change shapes!!!

The system is very flexible and allows you as a GM to make your own content in minutes without unbalancing the game; though you might find this intimidating, believe me it's not. You'd be surprised how many things you can run with this system. There's even a Ben 10 adaptation out there to give you an idea, and if you're gonna play it with kids, it's fun and simple enough to keep them interested :)

Comment: Hey, please read our guidance on system-rec questions.  So that they don't just degenerate into people pushing their favorite system all the time (Bad Subjective), we require answers to have experience with doing what it is the question's asking. "I'm sure system X would be great" is therefore not a legit answer; "I have used or seen system X used to do it" is.

Comment: Well I've only used 3 systems in my life... wouldn't really recommend the other two ... (4e and Aima: Beyond Fantasy).

Comment: Then don't answer please. Not trying to be mean, but we only allow system-rec questions because we have tight rules on them that make them not turn into junk.